# Using healpy spin transforms in a quicker way

Tags: healpy

I'm using a code that needs to do frequent spin-2 transforms in healpy using both map2alm and alm2map (predominantly the latter). However, when I go to higher and higher nside this transform inevitably becomes slower.

I am using healpy with openmp and due to the sheer volume of transforms necessary, this still results in a long time to complete a job. Is there any further way to try and speed up the transform that might be applicable to this situation? For example, as I am only interested in part of the sky, is there a way to only reconstruct the values in specified pixels and not the whole sky when using alm2map, and would this be quicker?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `healpy` can sped this up, but you might be interested in checking out the other Cl estimators, in case you're interested in the power spectra and not only the `alm`.

For the full sky (in HEALPix):

- [PolSpice](http://www2.iap.fr/users/hivon/software/PolSpice/)
- [XPol](https://gitlab.in2p3.fr/tristram/Xpol)

For smaller fields:

- [Poker](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011A%26A...535A..90P)

For reasons described [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002ApJ...567....2H), the estimation of the power spectra is not straightforward for a partially masked sky. HEALPy does not correct for this; the other packages I linked above do.